# Laravel 5.4 pluck

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have a problem with the laravel5.4 pluck function.

I need to obtain a list (to be used in a form::select) with a list of cities (cap_citta) and the corresponding zip codes (cap_cap) as keys.

In my code I have the following line:

```
$items = Cap::pluck('cap_citta', 'cap_cap');
```

The problem is that I obtain only a partial list.

If I write

```
$items = Cap::pluck('cap_citta');
```

instead everything goes right (but I'm missing the keys).

Comment: When you say a partial list, is this due to the fact that not all entries have a `cap_cap`?

Comment: In the database all the entries have a cap_cap (primary key) and a cap_citta. Taken individually or with a simple get() everything is ok, but with the pluck some pairs are missing.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are expecting. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Can multiple cities have the same zipcode? if that is the case you will always be missing some as you are keying by 'zipcode' so only 1 record per zipcode will be in your result as array keys are unique. A zipcode isn't unique enough to be an identifier.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was exactly that cap_cap is not unique.

Answer (score 4):

You are doing everything right with:

```
$items = Cap::pluck('cap_cap', 'cap_citta');
```

Are you sure all entries have a key - `cap_citta` ?

Comment: The keys are the cap_cap field in your example

Comment: Thank you, they are swapped now.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe

```
$collection = Cap::all();
$items = $collection->pluck('cap_citta', 'cap_cap');
```

Have a nice one!